# Python/VLC: changing playback speed through a 'while' loop

Tags: python, performance, while-loop, vlc, rate

I am very new to coding, and using Python for an animation exhibition. Basically I am writing code that will launch VLC player, play a series of random clips from my 'clips' dictionary, and play each clip at a random speed from my 'speed' dictionary.

The problem I am having is that once a speed is selected on the first 'while' looping, it plays every following clip at that speed. Is it possible to place the speed[speed_selection] element so that it re-chooses the speed for each clip selection?

Thank you in advance.

*edit: If I remove the "--one-instance" element, VLC opens each clip in a new VLC window each with its own speed from my dictionary of 4 speeds. SO, it's the "--one-instance" that is blocking the speed selection from setting more than one speed. I need "--one-instance" for my animation to play on one screen (of course), but that may be helpful in figuring out how I could possibly code this to change speed within the one instance of VLC.

```
clips = {1: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 1.mp4", 2: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 2.mp4", 3: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 3.mp4", 4: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 4.mp4", 5: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 5.mp4", 6: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 6.mp4", 7: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 7.mp4", 8: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 8.mp4", 9: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 9.mp4", 10: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 10.mp4", 11: "file:///C:/Users/Dan/Pictures/Bouchra UNI/Studio Practice 3/Moving drawing mp4s/for PYTHON short clips as mp4/clip 11.mp4"}

speed = {1: "--rate=1.0", 2: "--rate=1.5", 3: "--rate=2.0", 4: "--rate=0.5"}

import subprocess
from random import randint

timer = 0
while timer <= 19:
        selection = randint(1, 11)
        speed_selection = randint(1, 4)
        p = subprocess.Popen(["C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe","--one-instance","--fullscreen","--playlist-enqueue",speed[speed_selection],clips[selection]])
        timer += 1
```